# Horizontal spacing between subfloats using floatrow and subfig (with fr-subfig support)

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats, floatrow

I am trying to arrange two rows of sub-figures using `subfig` and `floatrow`. The captions are aligned as I wish and the vertical alignment of the objects is also fine. However, I cannot figure out how to get the horizontal spacing between the sub-figures even. In the bottom row, there is no problem: 2 figures with some space between. Fine. In the top row, however, there is more space between the first two figures than there is between the second and third figures. And I cannot figure out why.

[image: 5 sub-figures in 2 rows]

What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \floatbox{figure}{%
      \caption{%
        Components of the system: Penguins (\ref{fig:a}), Jumpers (\ref{fig:b}), Thingies (\ref{fig:c}), Cabbages (\ref{fig:d}) and Nuclear Warheads (\ref{fig:e})%
      }\label{fig:x}%
    }{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}%
    \subfloat[Penguins were here and here and here]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.125\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:c}}
  \end{subfloatrow}

  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}\label{fig:d}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguins were here, there and everywhere!]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:e}}
  \end{subfloatrow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I am aware of alternatives to `subfig`. If no solution is available for `subfig`, I'll hack something for now and look into other options for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

The `subfloatrowsep`, `floatrowsep` keys give you control on the horizontal separation between subfloats (floats) when using floatrow; however, simply using something like

```
\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad}
```

in your current code will *not* produce the desired result since you are using `\subfloat` (from the `subfig` package). The solution is not to use `\subfloat` and use `floatrow`'s `\ffigbox` instead. This makes

```
\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad}
```

behave as expected and also solves a problem with the counters (further discussed in [How can I get correct labelling of sub-figures with subfig and floatrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229022/3954)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}

\begin{document}

  \thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad}
  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
      \ffigbox{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}[3]%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguins were here and here and here}\label{fig:a}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]{example-image-a}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:b}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:c}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.125\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}

  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:d}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguins were here, there and everywhere!}\label{fig:e}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}%
      }{%
        \caption{Components of the system: Penguins (\ref{fig:a}), Jumpers (\ref{fig:b}), Thingies (\ref{fig:c}), Cabbages (\ref{fig:d}) and Nuclear Warheads (\ref{fig:e})\label{fig:x}}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

### Initial version

I've also had problems with horizontal positioning of figures using `floatrow` and the `floatrowsep`, `subfloatrowsep` keys seem to not always behave as expected.

One option that I've found to work in problematic cases is to  kill the default separation with `subfloatrowsep=none` and then use `\quad` or any other spacing command to manually control the separation (one would think that `subfloatrowsep=quad` would handle this automatically, but this is not always the case). Anyways, my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}

\begin{document}
  \thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=none}
  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \floatbox{figure}{%
      \caption{%
        Components of the system: Penguins (\ref{fig:a}), Jumpers (\ref{fig:b}), Thingies (\ref{fig:c}), Cabbages (\ref{fig:d}) and Nuclear Warheads (\ref{fig:e})%
      }\label{fig:x}%
    }{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}%
    \subfloat[Penguins were here and here and here]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.125\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:c}}
  \end{subfloatrow}

  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}\label{fig:d}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguins were here, there and everywhere!]{%
      \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}\label{fig:e}}
  \end{subfloatrow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tested this yet, but it makes sense. I tried all kinds of things in `\floatsetup...` and I couldn't figure out why keys which the docs say change horizontal spacing seemed to have zero effect, while other things seemed to work more-or-less as advertised. Since I'd never used the package, I assumed that must be me... Thanks again.

Comment: Though I may also have been trying to change the wrong thing... :(.

Comment: I managed to define and use a custom length for horizontal separation through `\DeclareFloatSeparators{halfgap}{\hskip0.5\columnsep}` and `\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=halfgap}`, but I also need to use such length in a `\fpeval` calculation, is it possible?