# How can I get correct labelling of sub-figures with subfig and floatrow?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, floatrow

I am using `subfig` and `floatrow` to manage sub-figures. Without `floatrow`, everything works OK, but I need `floatrow` to easily align the captions, as the `subfig` manual explains.

Adapting the example on page 37 of the manual and with [some help from Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228958/), I've got this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}

\begin{document}

  \thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=none}
  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \floatbox{figure}{%
      \caption{%
        Components of the system: Penguins (\ref{fig:a}), Jumpers (\ref{fig:b}), Thingies (\ref{fig:c}), Cabbages (\ref{fig:d}) and Nuclear Warheads (\ref{fig:e})%
      }\label{fig:x}%
    }{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}%
    \subfloat[Penguins were here and here and here]{%
      \label{fig:a}\includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]{example-image-a}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \label{fig:b}\includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \label{fig:c}\includegraphics[height=.125\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}

  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \subfloat[Penguin]{%
      \label{fig:d}\includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Penguins were here, there and everywhere!]{%
      \label{fig:e}\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:x} \ref{fig:a} \ref{fig:c} \ref{fig:e}

\end{document}
```

[image: mis-numbered sub-figures]

But obviously something is wrong with the caption numbering. This should all be figure 1 yet it begins with 4 and then increments by 2 more. I've tried moving the labels to different places but, although LaTeX will tell me references have changed, I still get the same result. I've also tried removing the `.aux` file etc. But, again, I still get 4 for the figure and 6 for the sub-figures.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: No idea how to solve this with `subfig` and switching to `subcaption` will imply a massive change in the approach.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I can't even figure out how to fake it. I can add `-3` to the `figure` counter just before the `figure` environment and that gets the main figure numbered correctly. But everywhere I try to adjust the counter within the figure creates weird results. I can't work out what and where the counter is being stepped! [I'm prepared to switch packages *after* this project, but I really don't want to try doing so in the middle. And page/line breaks prior to the bit I'm currently working on must not change else the new bit won't tally with the old (already distributed) bit...]

Comment: I think I found a solution (and I have an idea (a vague idea, really) of what was producing the undesired result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the correct output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}

\begin{document}

  \thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad}
  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
      \ffigbox{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}[3]%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguins were here and here and here}\label{fig:a}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]{example-image-a}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:b}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:c}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.125\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}

  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguin}\label{fig:d}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.15\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Penguins were here, there and everywhere!}\label{fig:e}}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
  \end{subfloatrow}%
      }{%
        \caption{Components of the system: Penguins (\ref{fig:a}), Jumpers (\ref{fig:b}), Thingies (\ref{fig:c}), Cabbages (\ref{fig:d}) and Nuclear Warheads (\ref{fig:e})\label{fig:x}}%
    }
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:x} \ref{fig:a} \ref{fig:c} \ref{fig:e}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem seems to be combining `floatrow` commands with subfig's `\subfloat` (I guess that using commands from both packages makes the counters step in a wrong way (when each package takes control, it steps the counters)); once everything is done using `floatrow` commands only, the problem disappears; notice that this will also make

```
  \thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad}
```

behave as expected, so no manual adjustments are needed now (I've added a remark about this also in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228957/3954)).

Comment: Weirdly, I was just about to edit my question to say that I'd found a solution for the labelling problem but that this solution broke the horizontal spacing again. However, setting `subfloatrowsep=qquad` solves the problem even without changing `\floatbox{figure}` to `ffigbox`. Thanks very much for looking into (& solving this)!