# Reduce space between content in floatrow

Tags: floatrow

I am using floatrow package to place image and table side-by-side. I use the following mark-up:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \includegraphics[height=.7\linewidth]{images/task_2/1_1.png}
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ | p{0.55cm} | p{0.55cm} | p{0.55cm} | p{0.55cm} | p{0.55cm} | }
    \hline
    0.003 & 0.013 & 0.22  & 0.003 & 0.003\\ \hline
    0.013 & 0.059 & 0.097 & 0.059 & 0.013\\ \hline
    0.22  & 0.097 & 0.159 & 0.097 & 0.022\\ \hline
    0.013 & 0.059 & 0.097 & 0.059 & 0.013\\ \hline
    0.003 & 0.013 & 0.22  & 0.003 & 0.003\\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}
  }
}{%
  \caption{A 5 $ \times $ 5 Gaussian kernel with $\sigma = $ 1 }%
  \label{table:Gaussian}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

The result i get looks like[image: this]

I would like the reduce the space between the image and the table. Could someone please help with this? I saw several similar questions but none of them (at least the ones I looked into) deals with floatrow package. I apologize if I missed a question.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. But you should remove the spaces you are adding as a first step. You can always add some spaces back if you decide you want them after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=none}` before your figure should reduce the spacing. You could look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228957/horizontal-spacing-between-subfloats-using-floatrow-and-subfig-with-fr-subfig-s) question's answers for more information.